# retrieve record and surrounding records in Entity Framework

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a table with thousands of records with a primary key called Id.

Over time records have been deleted so the Id structure looks like this:

Ids 1,2,5,7,12,15,17,34,45,89,97 ~ to 2567,2743,2981  etc

Using c# and Entity Framework, is there a way to locate a specific Id and retrieve it plus the next and previous ten records around it with a query?

I guess I am trying to capture a window of records. In a perfect list of 100 items, Lets say I need record 60, Is there a query that would retrieve records 50-70?

Answer (score 1):

In normal cases you should not care about the Ids, because they are automatic and not meant to be gapless (if you want to do something like that).

Nevertheless you can just select your entries with the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 11 Id FROM Table WHERE ID >= 400 ORDER BY ID UNION
SELECT TOP 11 Id From Table WHERE ID <= 400 ORDER BY ID Desc
```

Alternatively you could take a look into the RANGE function of SQL, which allows to nummerize the rows and then just select based on that number

And the EF version of the Select-Union:

```
idList.Where(id >= 400).OrderBy(id => id).Take(11).Union(
    idList.Where(id <= 400).OrderByDescending(id => id).Take(11));
```